# FormData doesn't get passed back to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload images and couple of form elements to a MVC Controller. The problem here isn't the model not being populated, because it works with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but seems to have trouble with `multipart/form-data`. The core of the problem is, that `Request.Form` is not being populated...

Converting Form to FormData:

```
function frmValuesAsFormData(submittedForm) {
    return new FormData(submittedForm);
}
```

AJAX Function (asFormData is passed in as True in this case and method is POST and dataType is JSON):

```
function executeAJAX(method, url, data, asFormData, silent, callbackFunc, receiveFunc, dataType, targetDiv, appendToExistingContent, uid) {

    var cType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var processData = true;

    if (asFormData) {
        cType = "multipart/form-data";
        processData = false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: cType,
        cache: false,
        dataType: dataType,
        processData: processData,
        success: function (d, t, j) {
            // Do something with result from controller...
        }
    });
}
```

POST Headers (From FireBug)

> Accept     application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate Accept-Language   en-GB,en;q=0.5
>   Content-Length     936 Content-Type    multipart/form-data Cookie 
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=mzppxvimv03qb0smtyrgdw3z Host    localhost:64727
>   Referer    http://localhost:64727/Home/Contact User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
>   X-Requested-With   XMLHttpRequest

POST Example (From FireBug):

> -----------------------------26439188689323 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageFiles"; filename="WWKDK33.jpg" Content-Type:
>   image/jpeg
>
> PNG  ��� IHDR��"��"����xÕj��7IDATxÚíÚKÂ
>   ÐÞÿÒz�B3~Þ,Õb|nHàøÈ!B"D"D!B$!B"D"D!B$
>   !B"Dcdtå]µ
>   B"D!BÔKtb_xv-!B"Dunð+¯uÔ"D!BÑS*ï"B"D!B(Õl
>   B"D!B
>   ô¢ïü·½ä~"D!B¢URi,ÖÕ"D!BQ/Q:ò[*E"D!B¨a¼ÙôWÿéf"D!B¢]
>   HæL~eD!B"DöÍ_ÉòGGkA"D!BèD±}Çõò4
>   !B"DZôÀ½rª�"D!B¢eD¡¡y¡éøk!B
>   "D!ZGÔ;¯49ÛD!B"D"cöÊ@fåQ^D!B"D®I4_à|Ci@J!B"DÝ(s°
>   "D!B¢{7 £ÌÁ"D!B"D½DgBæant¿"D!BÑÖý¤ôm
>   "D!B"D"D!B$!B"A"D!D!B"A"D!ß|ÜYÆ
>   ®«����IEND®B`
>   -----------------------------26439188689323 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaderMode"
>
> tournament
>   -----------------------------26439188689323--

Anyone any clues as to why it doesn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because when you send a `FormData` object in the request you have to set `contentType` to `false` so that no `content-type` header is sent. Try this:

```
if (asFormData) {
    cType = false;
    processData = false;
}
```

Also note that you could remove the need to send the `asFormData` property to your function entirely by just checking the type of the `data` property:

```
if (data.constructor == FormData) {
    cType = false;
    processData = false;
}
```

Comment: Man, you saved me here from hours of pain! :D
Works like a dream, thank you.